# How to use the onComplete in lua, corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm having trouble figuring out what th mistake, that I'm making is. I would be very glad if you could help me. I want one transition.to() happen after the other.

```
local ball = display.newCircle(160,0,30)

local function move()
ball.x = display.contentWidth/2
ball.y = display.contentWidth-display.contentWidth-ball.contentWidth*2
transition.to(ball, {x=display.contentWidth/2, y=display.contentHeight*1.3, time=5000, onComplete=move2})   
end

local function move2()
ball.x = display.contentWidth+ball.contentWidth/2
ball.y = 0-ball.contentWidth/2
transition.to(ball, {x=0-ball.contentWidth/2, y=display.contentHeight+ball.contentWidth/2, time = 5000})
--transition.to(ball,{x=160,y=240})
end

move()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your problem?

Try (tested)

```
local ball = display.newCircle(160,0,30)

local function move2()
    ball.x = display.contentWidth + ball.width * 0.5
    ball.y = -ball.width * 0.5
    transition.to(ball, {x=-ball.width * 0.5, y=display.contentHeight + ball.width * 0.5, time = 5000})
end

local function move()
    ball.x = display.contentWidth * 0.5
    ball.y = -ball.width * 2 
    transition.to(ball, {y=display.contentHeight * 1.3, time=5000, onComplete=move2})   
end

move()
```

Before you use function name you must declare variable with the same name or put function with body part above place where you first time use it.

If you want call `move` function again after `transition.to` in `move2` completed just use code below

```
local ball = display.newCircle(160,0,30)

local move

local function move2()
    ball.x = display.contentWidth + ball.width * 0.5
    ball.y = -ball.width * 0.5
    transition.to(ball, {x=-ball.width * 0.5, y=display.contentHeight + ball.width * 0.5, time = 5000, onComplete=move})
end

 function move()
    ball.x = display.contentWidth * 0.5
    ball.y = -ball.width * 2 
    transition.to(ball, {y=display.contentHeight * 1.3, time=5000, onComplete=move2})   
end

move()
```

Notice that you get infinity transitions. Read more about scopes for functions on Corona [blog](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2011/09/21/tutorial-scopes-for-functions/).

Comment: @Idurniat What should I do if I wanted to go to the function move() after the completion of the transition.to in function move2() (whivh is above of the move() function? I hope I am being clear about my problem.